# How do I solve the Servlet error in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, internal-server-error, requestdispatcher, servletexception

I have literally tried every solution present in the internet for this Error and none has worked for me. So, I'm asking again if anyone has any updated solution, then please help!.

As you can see in the dispatcher.xml file I have already tried using the ContextLoader, but it gave me a 404 File Not Found. I saw a similar post in Stack Overflow which said to mention the @Controller, but I had already done that and I was still getting the 404 Error.

I have also tried with the  load-on-startup 1 /load-on-startup approach but that still didn't work.

```
 Type Exception Report

    Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

    Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the 
    request.
 
    Exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Here are my files:

Web.xml

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
         <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
         </listener-class>
    </listener> -->
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mayukh.Project"/>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        name="dataSource" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/projectdb" p:username="root"
        p:password="test" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        name="sessionFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mayukh.Project.entity.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate"
        name="hibernateTemplate" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name="transactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        name="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Controller:

```
 package com.mayukh.Project.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    import com.mayukh.Project.entity.User;
    import com.mayukh.Project.services.UserService;

    @Controller
    public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping("registrationPage")
    public String showRegistrationPage() {
        return "userReg";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap model) {
        int result = service.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("result", "User created with ID " + result);
        return "regResult";
    }

    public UserService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```